# Detect in which Express middleware the code in running

Tags: node.js, express

Suppose this:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();


const mw1 = (req, res, next) => console.log("Hello from position: " + ?);
const mw2 = (req, res, next) => console.log("Hello from position: " + ?);

app.get('/test', mw1, mw2, (req, res) => { 

  req.logger("Hello from controller!");

});
```

Is it possible by maybe using the *req* variable to know from within the middleware where in the chain I am without having to explicitly write it down as literal in the console message?

And by "where in the chain I am" I mean in the chain of middlewares. In this particular example mw1 since it is the first it should be in index 0, mw2 in index 1, but if change the position of the middlewares the indexes should change too.

There is something called stack that you can access from **req.route.stack**, which gives you information about the chain, but it does not tell you where you are.

Comment: Perhaps using some sort of stack tracer like `stacktracey` and a function that will return the callee: `const getName = () => new StackTracey().items[1].callee` (and use it like `console.log("Hello from position:", getName())`). But I wonder what your actual use case is.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use something like this?

```
 const middleware2 = (request, response) => {
    // response.locals = 'middleware2'; // Any other object structure that suits you

   let currentMethod = arguments.callee.toString();
   currentMethod = currentMethod.substr('function '.length);     
   currentMethod = currentMethod.substr(0, me.indexOf('('));  

   response.locals = currentMethod; 

   // Middleware stuff here
   //........

    next()
}
```

The `request.locals` could be any object you like

Comment: That seems rather explicit.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question "without having to explicitly write it down as literal". The middleware can be randomly placed on the change

Comment: Just edited the my answer. But if you are in strict mode it will throw a type error. You used to be able to get the current method name, but I think that ability was removed